# rxjs how to pass observable to map

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm new to angular and rxjs - basically I have a pipe function that takes a few operators, and one of them takes a 'map' with a ternary that is either an empty array or another observable which is a value coming from an http request:

```
search = (text: Observable<string>) => {
  return text.pipe(
    debounceTime(200),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map(term => term.length < 3 ? [] : performSearch(text))
  );
}


performSearch(searchTerm: Observable<string>): Observable<Object> {
  return this.http.get('/api/header-search-results/con').pipe(
    map(res => {
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    })
  );
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, I just don't know what - I'm getting an error in the browser:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

I'd appreciate any guidance

Comment: Please also show your template code

Comment: It looks like you are iterating over an Observable, missed `subscribe()` or `async`?

Comment: @AshishRanjan I'm using `[ngbTypeahead]="search"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your implementation, `merge` operator returns either an observable or an object. I suggest you use only objects, or only observables. If you're choosing the second solution, you should also consider an operator that will flatten your stream : `concatMap, mergeMap, switchMap, ...` according to your needs.

Example of implementation:

```
search = (text: Observable<string>) => {
  return text.pipe(
    debounceTime(200),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    concatMap(term => term.length < 3 ? of([]) : performSearch(text))
  );
}


performSearch(searchTerm: Observable<string>): Observable<Object> {
  return this.http.get('/api/header-search-results/con').pipe(
    map(res => {
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return an empty array then just wrap it with `of()` (in RxJS 6) and then instead of `map` use `mergeMap` that will subscribe to the inner Observable returned.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

...

search = (text: Observable<string>) => {
  return text.pipe(
    debounceTime(200),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    mergeMap(term => term.length < 3 ? of([]) : performSearch(text))
  );
}
```

Comment: FYI - accepted other guy's answer only cuz he can probably use the points